# MVVM solution structure: should project partition be vertical (by feature) or horizontal (by layer)?

Tags: mvvm, architecture, solution

I'm working in a suite of applications that perform data acquisition in a healthcare setting. The idea is to have a common infra-structure (including hardware IO, file IO, common domain model) and a thin top layer with separate projects for specifics of each health speciality.

The Model layer is a Rich Domain Model, containing mostly the Domain datatypes.
On top of the Model layer, there is the Business layer, dealing mostly with workflows. For example, there is the `CaptureConductor` class, taking an `ICaptureDevice`, an `IPlotterModel` and an `IFileWriter` class (each one from the Domain Model), and making them work together. I have also `AnalysisConductor`, `AnalysisReportModel`, `DeviceConfigurationConductor`, and other classes dealing with higher-level workflows.

Then I have some ViewModels, where each one tend to map to one or just a handful of objects from the Business layer (which I consider still to be in the "Model" part of MVVM). So, the "SomeFeatureViewModel" maps to "SomeFeatureModel", and the "OtherFeatureViewModel" maps to "OtherFeatureViewModel", etc.

Since I'm using a MVVM framework (MVVM Light in this case), I decided to "concentrate" this dependency in one single project, so I created one ViewModel project containing a lot of somewhat unrelated ViewModels.

So my question is: Is this a good partition?

On one hand, on doing this (horizontal partitioning), I concentrate the framework dependency in the ViewModel layers and above, and so the Model layers can be "pure". But this gives me low cohesion (ViewModel project containing lots of unrelated stuff), and high coupling (each time I need a ViewModel, I need to reference that one large project.

On the other hand, if I partition vertically, that is, I let View and ViewModel live together in each project, grouped by functionality, I get a much better (IMO) cohesion and lower coupling, with the downside referencing the framework in almost every project.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must group features together based on [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I think in most cases `ViewModel` tend to change together with the `View` and as such they should be placed into a single package.

Your `ViewModel` project feels somehow disconnected to me. It is neither UI layer of your software, nor business logic layer. It is a piece of UI, which is separated from it on unknown reason.

Also I think different project of yours may require different `ViewModel`s to be connected to a single `Model`, right?

So, I think your business logic layer should be a framework. And `View`s + `ViewModel`s should be different projects for each health speciality. These projects can extend your framework if need comes.

Does this suite your needs?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Actually, every health specialty will present the same captured data in different ways (so the user can perform specialty-specific operation on data), but the underlying conduction of data capture would be, for any effect, identical between specialties. That's why I make the ViewModel as a _wrapper_ to a given Model (one-to-one relationship), while each specific application would have a different View (one-to-many ViewModel/Views relationship). Do you think that would make sense?

Comment: (refining previous comment) for example, I currently refactored the CaptureModel and CaptureViewModel to a project called _CaptureService_, so that every application dealing with data-capture can reference this "Service" assembly containing the Model (business logic) and it's wrapping ViewModel (a data-binding-based Façade to different possible Views).

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to partition your ViewModels into several projects with related ViewModels together. That will improve somewhat cohesion and lower overall coupling.